# Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - "Could not start a new session" in SoapUI Groovy TestStep

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, webdriver, soapui

I use SoapUI Pro 5.1.2 on Win7 x32, and try to connect to Selenium Webdriver in Groovy TestStep.

For this purpose I added `selenium-standalone-server.jar` v2.45.0 in `$SOAP_HOME$\bin\ext` folder.

My Groovy TestStep code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', 'C:\\\\Windows\\system32\\chromedriver.exe')
log.info(System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')) //got 'C:\\Windows\system32\chromedriver.exe'

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() // this line causes error

driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

When I try to run this step, SoapUI returns message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. 
Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Build info: 
    version: '2.45.0', 
    revision: '5017cb8', 
    time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50' 
System info: 
    host: 'SmithPC', 
    ip: '10.0.2.15', 
    os.name: 'Windows 7', 
    os.arch: 'x86', 
    os.version: '6.1', 
    java.version: '1.8.0_45' 
Driver info: 
    driver.version: ChromeDriver 
error at line: 7
```

I tried to run this piece of code through the *Netbeans IDE*, after adding the same `selenium-standalone-server.jar` package to empty java project. **And it has completed without problems!**

This is error-log of soapUI:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'SmithPC', ip: '10.0.2.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at Script3.run(Script3.groovy:7)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:138)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 23 more
```

I also tried use `FirefoxDriver()` instead of `ChromeDriver()`, and got the same error.

Comment: Looks like `chromedriver.exe` starts normally- at least soapUI log in terminal shows message `Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (hashcode) on port 36240` right before error message

Comment: I tried to run `FirefoxDriver()` without any pre-configuring - the simplest way to launch browser - but it throws the same error too

Comment: I've got the same error, my solution was an older version of Chrome

Answer (score 13):

I have encountered the same error, which said:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

but `chromedriver.exe` started fine. I can see it in task manager.

My environment is as following,

- windows 7, ultimate, 64 bit system
- selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1
- chromedriver 2.19
- google chrome: 45.0

After many tries suggested in google results, my final solution is to add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Can also be a problem if you have a bogus localhost entry. In short, it appears, selenium only likes 127.0.0.1 localhost as your localhost entry.

Answer (score 6):

Download latest driver(chrome or IE) from seleniumhq.org, and use below code

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<YourPath>chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

This worked for me.

Comment: updating the chromedriver helped me.

Answer (score 5):

In selenium this error message:

> **org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:** Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.

Could have a lot of causes. However looking at the stacktrace in this case is due to a `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
```

The problem is that you're using selenium inside SOAPUI. SOAPUI seems to set the default proxy to `null` (`ProxySelector.setDefault(null)`). So when selenium gets the default proxy an invoke a method on it, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

The problem is that you executes your code inside SOAPUI so you can not get the default proxy before SOAPUI set it to null... then a possible workaround is in your Groovy testStep try to create a `ProxySelector` an set it as default before `WebDriver` is executed:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import java.net.Proxy
import java.net.ProxySelector

def selectDirectProxy(URI uri) {
  final List<Proxy> proxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>()
  proxy.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
  return proxy
}

// create a ProxySelector
ProxySelector proxySelector = [ select : { uri->selectDirectProxy(uri) } ] as ProxySelector
// set as default to avoid null pointer
ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);

// now it's safe to invoke WebDriver...
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', 'C:\\\\Windows\\system32\\chromedriver.exe')
log.info(System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')) //got 'C:\\Windows\system32\chromedriver.exe'

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
```

In this example I extend the `ProxySelector` abstract class in a groovy way, to set at least one direct proxy. If its necessary it's also possible to use the `Proxy` class to configure a no direct proxy and set it in the list, but with this code I'm trying to avoid the `NPE` due to SOAPUI `ProxySelector.setDefault(null)`.

Comment: Really cool trick. I used to run webdriver inside SoapUI older versions (4.xx) and your post helped me to run it in new versions :)

Answer (score 0):

It already told you what happened:

```
//got 'C:**\\**Windows\system32\chromedriver.exe'
```

Try to define path using one of the next ways:

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver','C:\\Windows\\system32\\chromedriver.exe')
log.info(System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver'))
```

OR

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver','C:/Windows/system32/chromedriver.exe')
log.info(System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver'))
```

Also, I would not recommend you to store chromedriver.exe in system32 folder, especially if you don't have admin rights on the workstation. Use smt like C:/WebDrivers/hromedriver.exe

Comment: It's not that ChromeDriver executable path is wrong, for this java throws `IllegalStateException`: "The driver executable does not exist". I tried to change directory of driver, placing new copy of `chromedriver.exe` in `C:\drivers`, but it's not help - the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a compatibility issue between the 'selenium', 'chrome browser version' and 'chrome driver' version that you are using.

It you are using Selenium 2.53 (like me), then using chrome driver 2.25 should work for you.

You can download it from here - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and upgrading to the latest chrome driver fixed my issue.

You can download the latest chrome driver from following URL.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

It is best to use always the latest version. After downloading, set the path of chrome driver in System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","{Your path Chrome Driver}");

```
    System.out.println("Creating Chrome Driver");
 // Set Chrome Driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("{Your URL}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is totally related to the chrome browser version and chrome driver version.

Once you keep both browser and driver versions the same, your problem will get resolved.

To check the chrome version go to the following steps ->> Click on three vertical dots ->> Help ->> About Google Chrome Browser ->> see the chrome version.

[image]

Now check the chrome BROWSER version

[image]

in my case browser version is 90.0

Now download the same version of the chrome driver respective of the operating system

We will download the 90.0 version of driver, then set the browser path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\chromedriver.exe");

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("{Your URL}")
```

#JAVA #SELENIUM

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If someone encountered a similar problem on Ubuntu, please check if you install Chrom**ium** web browser [image]

Not enough to have only chrome browser.

[More details](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/28441/44698)