# After run a SoapUI, could not start selenium

Tags: java, session, selenium, soapui

I got a problem. I run a SoapUI web service test through my Java automation code. But After that. Selenium doesn't work. It seems soapUI part not actually done. But I'm not sure.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SoapUIRun srun = new SoapUIRun();
    srun.runTestCase("CPIHS", "CPIHS");
    new MainPage().LoginCad();
}
```

The exception msg is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'GFG-GROUP153', ip: '10.100.1.7', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at screens.MainPage.LoginCad(MainPage.java:28)
    at screens.MainPage.main(MainPage.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 13 more
```

However is I comment out SoapUI part. It will work again. Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //SoapUIRun srun = new SoapUIRun();
    //srun.runTestCase("CPIHS", "CPIHS");
    new MainPage().LoginCad();
}
```

Here is my SoapUI method:

```
public void runTestCase(String tarSuite, String tarCase) throws Exception {

    String reportStr = "";

    TestRunner runner;

    SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));

    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:\\Users\\tshi\\Documents\\Maven Projects\\ASORT\\WebServiceResource\\Suncorp_Issuing-soapui-project.xml");

    List<TestSuite> suiteList = project.getTestSuiteList();

    for (TestSuite aSuiteList : suiteList) {

        String suiteName = aSuiteList.getName();

        List<TestCase> caseList = aSuiteList.getTestCaseList();
        //System.out.println("Test Suite: " + suiteName);

        if (suiteName.equals(tarSuite)) {

            for (TestCase aCaseList : caseList) {

                String caseName = aCaseList.getName();
                //System.out.println("Test Case: " + caseName);

                if (caseName.equals(tarCase)) {

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    runner = project.getTestSuiteByName(suiteName).getTestCaseByName(caseName).run(new PropertiesMap(), false);

                    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    reportStr = reportStr + "\n\tTestCase: " + aCaseList.getName() + "\tStatus: " + runner.getStatus() + "\tReason: " + runner.getReason() + "\tDuration: " + duration;

                    System.out.print(reportStr);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is Selenium related method:

```
public void LoginCad(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");

    String bank = Integer.toString(48);
    String emp = Integer.toString(200003);
    String pwd = "Cadencie1";
    String baseUrl = "http://172.16.1.133:8090/AppName/servlet/app";

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get(baseUrl);

    try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e){

        // TO DO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Utilities.switchToWindow("AppName - User Logon [LOGON]", driver);

    try{

        Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e){

        // TO DO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("idBANK")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idBANK")).sendKeys(bank);

    driver.findElement(By.id("idEMPLOYEE")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idEMPLOYEE")).sendKeys(emp);

    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).sendKeys(pwd);

    driver.findElement(By.id("maintLOGON")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("idPASSWORD")).sendKeys(pwd);

    driver.findElement(By.id("maint")).click();

}
```

Anyone has any idea why this happen. I searched on google. But it seems nobody gets same error in the same situation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397043/selenium-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-in-soapui) thread helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, they are not working.

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again? Reinstall all off those involved programs and see if that will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem only happens with selenium after *SOAPUI* execution then probably some *SOAPUI* configuration is causing the issue. The issue is probably due because *SOAPUI* is setting the default proxy to `null`, then when *selenium* try to gets the proxy to check the configuration receive the `NullPointerExcetpion`.

Based on you error trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:79)
```

If you take a look at the source code of [`org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.groupbyinc/common-http/23/org/apache/http/impl/conn/SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java#SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.0proxySelector) class:

(Note I keep the line  number to correlates with your error trace)

```
53 public class More ...SystemDefaultRoutePlanner extends DefaultRoutePlanner {
54 
55     private final ProxySelector proxySelector;
56 
57     public More ...SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(
58             final SchemePortResolver schemePortResolver,
59             final ProxySelector proxySelector) {
60         super(schemePortResolver);
         /*
           proxySelector ARE NULL AND ProxySelector.getDefault(); 
           RETURNS ALSO NULL DUE THAT SOAPUI PROBABLY MAKE BEFORE
           ProxySelect.setDefault(null);
         */
61         this.proxySelector = proxySelector != null ? proxySelector : ProxySelector.getDefault();
62     }
63 
64     public More ...SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(final ProxySelector proxySelector) {
65         this(null, proxySelector);
66     }
67 
68     @Override
69     protected HttpHost More ...determineProxy(
70             final HttpHost    target,
71             final HttpRequest request,
72             final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
73         final URI targetURI;
74         try {
75             targetURI = new URI(target.toURI());
76         } catch (final URISyntaxException ex) {
77             throw new HttpException("Cannot convert host to URI: " + target, ex);
78         }
           /* HERE IS THE NULLPOINTER */
79         final List<Proxy> proxies = this.proxySelector.select(targetURI);
```

## Workaround

So a possible solution is to take care of the `ProxySelect` yourself. Then you can try with the follow workaround:

```
import java.net.ProxySelector;
...

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // get default proxy before soapui will set it to null
    ProxySelector proxy = ProxySelector.getDefault();

    SoapUIRun srun = new SoapUIRun();
    srun.runTestCase("CPIHS", "CPIHS");

    // set it again to avoid NPE on selenium
    ProxySelector.setDefault(proxy);

    new MainPage().LoginCad();
}
```

Comment: This is awesome Albciff. It totally solves my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @albciff for your workaround, but it didnt help in my case.
I have finally created new Proxy:

```
report.step("Verify 'proxySelector' not NULL");
ProxySelector proxy = ProxySelector.getDefault();
if (proxy == null) {
    //Creating new Proxy
    ProxySelector proxySelector = new ProxySelector() {
        @Override
        public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
            return new ArrayList<Proxy>(){{
                add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
            }};
        }

        @Override
        public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        }
    };

    report.report("Set new proxySelector (Proxy.NO_PROXY)", Reporter.WARNING);
    ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);

}else{
    report.report("Proxy is not NULL continue..");
}
```