# UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium. Able to configure selenium set up on Ubuntu.Configuration details given below:

- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.84
- ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706)
- Jenkins ver. 2.193
- ubuntu-18.04
- Selenium 3.13.0
- OpenJDK 1.8
- Doc referred for selenium set up : https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/

But every run I am getting below error on jenkins :

```
Opening chrome driver
Oct 30, 2019 1:26:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.998 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] setUp(com.test.WebAppTitleTestOnChrome)  Time elapsed: 0.895 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - "Could not start a new session" in SoapUI Groovy TestStep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397043/selenium-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-in-soapui)

Comment: Check the browser version and the driver version you are using. Both should be compatible with the Selenium version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. 
Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue possibly is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome= 68.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **unknown** to us.
- Your *JDK version* is **unknown** to us.

So there might be a mismatch between the *JDK version* , *Selenium Client version* , *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v68.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine for me. Upgraded the level as you suggested. Thanks much :).

Comment: "Supports Chrome v67-69" doesn't mean "Supports Chrome v67 + v68 + v69" ? It's not a range of versions ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens.

- When the test does not get executed within 3 minutes(Default timing) then it will throw the exception of browser startup failure.

Solution:-
Change the way to create RemoteWebDriver.

```
  ClientConfig config = ClientConfig.defaultConfig().connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
.readTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20)); // I change this 3 minute(Default) to 20 minutes.

WebDriver remoteWebDriver = RemoteWebDriver.builder().oneOf(caps).address(gridUrl).config(config).build(); // now you can use this remoteWebDriver.
```

Comment: Is it idle to wait for 20 minutes for test case to run.

I am facing this issue only on remote execution on Perfecto,Brwoserstack.
On Local environment this works fine.

Comment: You can specify your own.

Answer (score 1):

For mac, there are 2 option for chrome driver
[chromedriver mac 1 or 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlhKc.png)

1. chromedriver_mac64.zip OR 2. chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip

Now, Go to file > Right click and "Open with terminal" > Provide required access.
[open in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwLXT.png)
Now, run command "mvn clean install" again, It works.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that the:

- path is incorrect,
- the path had .exe extension for mac driver
- typo on the path, I had a comma instead of dot webdriver.chrome,driver

Lastly, it could be the compatibility issue but all worked fine after checking above items

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error is bit inappropriate. I too had the same issue but while using GRID and the problems were two.

1. Selenium GRID / server version and the selenium lib used in code are different versions (4.9.0 and 4.8.3)
   [Selenium server version img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaD5r.png)
   [Selenium lib in code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM3y6.png)
2. Capability values were incorrect - Incorrect platform was chosen
   WIN10 instead of WIN11
   `DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities(); cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10); cap.setBrowserName("chrome"); WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue to this when I was using the image `selenium/standalone-chrome:114.0` and explicitly setting the browser version in the Java code

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.setBrowserVersion(browserVersion);
```

This was causing the issue whenever the `browserVersion` was malformed, which includes when the version was `114` without the trailing `.0`. The solution was to simply set the browser version to exactly `114.0`.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you see error as following .... then that is mostly because of your dependencies mismatch. To avoid this please try to use latest versions of your dependencies

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

**Possible dependencies:**

- java-client
- selenium-java [Note: selenium-java will have
  selenium-support so if your pom having both then you can remove
  selenium-support dependency from pom
- selenium-support